# tenses on both sides of "as"

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Does the "as" in the following indicate two things happened at the same time?
If so, is it natural for one tense to be present perfect and for the other to be simple past?

> A missing Indonesian submarine **has been found**, broken into at least three parts, at the bottom of the Bali Sea, army and navy officials said on Sunday, **as** the president **sent** condolences to relatives of the 53 crew.

Comment: I find the cited text "clumsy", but it's syntactically fine. Note that ***as*** here (meaning "at the same time") doesn't refer back to *[the submarine, which] **has been found***. Obviously the president couldn't be sending condolences at the same time as the sub was being found, since he couldn't know anything about that until some time later.  It refers to ***officials said** [on Sunday]*.

Comment: Thank you. You really pointed out the key issue, which many people have not noticed.